# How to parameterize a non-deterministic function in pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Say I have a function which returns a random item from a list:

```
def get_item(L):
    if not L: return None
    return random.choice(L)
```

How can I use [parameterization](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html) with `pytest` to test both cases?

Comment: Why do you want to test exactly ? I advice you to take a look at Mocking and inversion-of-control

Comment: `random.choice` is not really random, it's deterministic once you know the seed. So you can always get the ground truth.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass in parameters which give a deterministic result:

```
result = get_item(None)
assert result is None

result = get_item([42])
assert result == 42

random.seed(1)
result = get_item([1,2,3])
assert result == 1
```

Comment: What about `get_item([1,2,3])` ?

Comment: Use `random.seed(1)` and see what comes out. Assert for that every time.